# How do "de-embed" words in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I am trying to follow the tutorial for [Language Modeling](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#language-modeling) on the TensorFlow site.  I see it runs and the cost goes down and it is working great, but I do not see any way to actually get the predictions from the model.  I tried following the instructions at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179218/getting-word-from-id-at-tensorflow-rnn-sample) but the tensors returned from session.run are floating point values like 0.017842259, and the dictionary maps words to integers so that does not work.

How can I get the predicted word from a tensorflow model?

Edit: I found this [explanation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/97) after searching around, I just am not sure what x and y would be in the context of this example.  They don't seem to use the same conventions for this example as they do in the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor you are mentioning is the `loss`, which defines how the network is training. For prediction, you need to access the tensor `probabilities` which contain the probabilities for the next word. If this was classification problem, you'd just do `argmax` to get the top probability. But, to also give lower probability words a chance of being generated,some kind of sampling is often used.

Edit: I assume the code you used is [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py). In that case, if you look at line 148 (`logits`) which can be converted into probabilities by simply applying the `softmax` function to it -- like shown in the pseudocode in tensorflow website. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by this.  The result of `session.run` is a 3 element list with the elements being as follows: cost: a float32 that I assume is the average cost of the model, eval_op: the function used to evaluate the model, and final_state: a list of LSTMStateTuples

Comment: Which one of those contains the probabilities?

Comment: One more thing to mention, these LSTMStateTuples contain negative values so I am assuming they are not probabilities (but also I'm not sure how something would have negative loss)

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be one of the outputs of the network. In the example you have linked, there is a probabilities tensor. You can access the values of that tensor [multiple ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)

Comment: From your edit, which talks about simple MNIST example, I feel like it would help you a lot to go through the basic mechanics of tensorflow first. Tensorflow has very good documentation.

Comment: So I think you answered the wrong question there.  I'm asking how to access the probabilities tensor.  I can print the values from it once I have it, I just don't know where it is since session.run only has `cost`, `eval_op` and `final_state`.  So, how do I get probabilities from these variables?

Comment: Ah, I think I see where you are getting confused.  In the documentation, it includes the `probabilities` variable in the pseudocode but if you look at the actual code on git, there is no `probabilities` variable

Comment: Ahh, but the code posted is also pretty similar. It has `logits` in there which is just a [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function away from getting the probs. See my edit.

Comment: I see what you mean there.  I did not make that connection beforehand, but that is really helpful and now I see how I can make this work with the examples that are there.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So after going through a bunch of other similar posts I figured this out.  First, the code explained in the documentation is not the same as the code on the GitHub repository.  The current code works by initializing models with data inside instead of passing data to the model as it goes along.

So basically to accomplish what I was trying to do, I reverted my code to commit [9274f5a](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9274f5aa478879386870bb0cb889e432d4aee330/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) (also do the same for reader.py).  Then I followed the steps taken in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286594/predicting-the-next-word-using-the-lstm-ptb-model-tensorflow-example?rq=1) to get the `probabilities` tensor in my `run_epoch` function.  Additionally, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179218/getting-word-from-id-at-tensorflow-rnn-sample?noredirect=1&lq=1) to pass the `vocabulary` to my `main` function.  From there, I inverted the dict using `vocabulary = {v: k for k, v in vocabulary.items()}` and passed it to `run_epoch`.

Finally, we can get the predicted word in `run_epoch` by running `current_word = vocabulary[np.argmax(prob, 1)]` where `prob` is the tensor returned from `session.run()`

Edit:  Reverting the code as such should not be a permanent solution and I definitely recommend using @Prophecies answer above to get the `probabilities` tensor.  However, if you want to get the word mapping, you will need to pass the vocabulary as I did here.